# How to change heading tag upon button click using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The heading tag should say "Marco " to begin with and the button shows "polo". onClick they should interchange. I'm using useState and an array to do the job. They should keep interchanging. But after a round, they repeat. I guess on the third round. I cannot understand why this is happening.

> ```
> import React, { useState } from "react";
> import "../styles/App.css";
> const App = () => {
>   let arr = ["Marco", "Polo"];
>   const [input, setInput] = useState(arr[0]);
>   const [inputButton, setInputBUtton] = useState(arr[1]);
>   const changethis = () => {
>     // console.log("Clicked");
>     // console.log(arr);
>     let temp = arr[0];
>     arr[0] = arr[1];
>     arr[1] = temp;
>     console.log(arr);
>     setInput(arr[0]);
>     setInputBUtton(arr[1]);
>   };
>
>   return (
>     <div id="main">
>       <h1 id="marco-polo">{input}</h1>
>       <button id="marco-polo-toggler" onClick={changethis}>
>         {inputButton}
>       </button>
>     </div>
>   );
> };
>
> export default App;
> ```

when I console log my array I'm getting like this.

```
(2) ['Polo', 'Marco']
(2) ['Polo', 'Marco']
(2) ['Marco', 'Polo']
(2) ['Polo', 'Marco']
(2) ['Polo', 'Marco']
(2) ['Marco', 'Polo']
(2) ['Polo', 'Marco']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every time you change the state the component rerender and your `arr` is reset

you can either put your array outside your component so it is not redefined every render or you can use a state index instead

**solution 1**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../styles/App.css";
let arr = ["Marco", "Polo"];

const App = () => {

  const [input, setInput] = useState(arr[0]);
  const [inputButton, setInputBUtton] = useState(arr[1]);
  const changethis = () => {
    // console.log("Clicked");
    // console.log(arr);
    let temp = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[1];
    arr[1] = temp;
    console.log(arr);
    setInput(arr[0]);
    setInputBUtton(arr[1]);
  };

  return (
    <div id="main">
      <h1 id="marco-polo">{input}</h1>
      <button id="marco-polo-toggler" onClick={changethis}>
        {inputButton}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**solution 2**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../styles/App.css";
const App = () => {
  let arr = ["Marco", "Polo"];
  const [input, setInput] = useState(0);
  const [inputButton, setInputBUtton] = useState(1);
  const changethis = () => {
    // console.log("Clicked");
    // console.log(arr);
   
    setInput(i => (i + 1) % arr.length);
    setInputBUtton(i => (i + 1) % arr.length);
  };

  return (
    <div id="main">
      <h1 id="marco-polo">{arr[input]}</h1>
      <button id="marco-polo-toggler" onClick={changethis}>
        {arr[inputButton]}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

`arr` is redeclared each render cycle with the value `["Marco", "Polo"]` and every third time they are swapped the enqueued state update is to the same value the state already is, so that rerender is skipped.

## Solution

Move the `arr` array declaration outside the component so its reference is stable. Instead of mutating an `arr` variable that is redeclared each render cycle, you should just swap the state values.

Example:

```
const arr = ["Marco", "Polo"];

export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(arr[0]);
  const [inputButton, setInputBUtton] = useState(arr[1]);

  const changethis = () => {
    setInput(inputButton);
    setInputBUtton(input);
  };

  return (
    <div id="main">
      <h1 id="marco-polo">{input}</h1>
      <button id="marco-polo-toggler" onClick={changethis}>
        {inputButton}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-change-heading-tag-upon-button-click-using-react]

If you still wanted to swap the `arr` array values you should still move the `arr` array out of the component so its value isn't reset each render. Use array destructuring assignment to swap the array values.

Example:

```
const arr = ["Marco", "Polo"];

export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(arr[0]);
  const [inputButton, setInputBUtton] = useState(arr[1]);

  const changethis = () => {
    [arr[1], arr[0]] = [arr[0], arr[1]]; // swap element values
    console.log(arr);
    setInput(arr[0]);
    setInputBUtton(arr[1]);
  };

  return (
    <div id="main">
      <h1 id="marco-polo">{input}</h1>
      <button id="marco-polo-toggler" onClick={changethis}>
        {inputButton}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can manage your array in the state, and then you can perform an operation very easily. Maybe the below code will helpful for you.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [arr, setArray] = useState(['Marco', 'Polo']);
  const [input, setInput] = useState(arr[0]);
  const [inputButton, setInputBUtton] = useState(arr[1]);
  const changethis = () => {
    let temp = [];
    temp.push(arr[1], arr[0]);
    console.log(arr);
    setArray(temp);
    setInput(arr[0]);
    setInputBUtton(arr[1]);
  };

  return (
    <div id="main">
      <h1 id="marco-polo">{input}</h1>
      <button id="marco-polo-toggler" onClick={changethis}>
        {inputButton}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 words "Marco" & "Polo" which get switched between the heading & the button.
So your `App` component needs to store the order in its `state`.

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // store word order in state
        this.state = {words: ['Marco','Polo']};
    }

    // use arrow functions for event listeners to avoid "this" problem
    invert=(evt)=> {
        // use callback argument of setState when using current state value
        this.setState((state)=>{
            // reverse word order
            return state.words.reverse();
        });
    }


    // show 1st word in h1 & 2nd word in button
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="main">
                <h1 id="marco-polo">{this.state.words[0]}</h1>
                <button id="marco-polo-toggler" onClick={this.invert}> 
                    {this.state.words[1]}
                </button>
            </div>
         );
    }
}
```